# Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Material.color' for changing alpha of gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with this, although this is just for improvement for my code I can make the gameobject change it's alpha I just want it simpler.

here is my code:

```
SpriteRenderer go;
Color colora;
float x = 0f;
void Start () {
    go = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    colora = new Color(255f,255f,255f,.5f);
    go.material.color.a = colora.a;
}
```

this is the error one. just to make this code simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color is a struct and it is valueType.

```
go.material.color // it will return a copy of Color
```

You have to make another instance of Color then assign back to go.material.color

```
go.material.color = new Color(255f,255f,255f,.5f);
```

Comment: yah that's what i've done. I only want to change the alpha channel that's all . Anyway to do it like this "asdasdd.color.a = 0f"

Comment: If you want to only change the alpha then you have to do this 
Color c = go.material.color;
c.a = newValue;
go.material.color = c;